# AppCompat Button Theme Issue

Tags: android, material-design

[image]

How to remove space between blue border and actual button border?
Corners of button have small black dots.
Below is the Button code

```
<android.support.v7.widget.AppCompatButton
     android:id="@+id/btn_signup_login"
     android:layout_width="match_parent"
     android:layout_height="wrap_content"
     android:theme="@style/Control.Button.Normal.Gray"
     android:layout_marginTop="@dimen/dimen_16dp"
     android:foreground="?android:selectableItemBackground"
     app:backgroundTint="@color/transparent"
     android:padding="@dimen/dimen_16dp"
     android:elevation="@dimen/dimen_2dp"
     android:text="@string/btn_login" />
```

and theme is as below

```
<style name="Control.Button.Normal.Gray">
    <item name="backgroundTint">@color/transparent</item>
    <item name="android:padding">0dp</item>
</style>
```

[image]
This theme also creates problem for ripple effect

How to remove this ripple effect as well?

Comment: set background  **`android:background="@color/white"`**

Comment: this is not working

Comment: try my answer @mangesh

Answer (score 0):

Just remove `selectableItemBackground`  to remove ripple effect

```
 android:foreground="?android:selectableItemBackground"
```

And set `background` as `white` to remove that default drawable,

```
android:background="@android:color/white"
```

your theme `Control.Button.Normal.Gray` is not needed